# How to detect noise in images

Tags: c++, opencv

How to detect noise in images?

I need to do some preprocessing before OCR and I need to detect if there are areas with noise? How to detect these areas? They are typically in rectangular areas

Below is an example. There are some noise in the last column to the right. I need the bounding boxes for all the areas with noise

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could sweep a kernel through the image and calculate the standard deviation in this kernel. If it is above an empirical threshold you could say there is noise in this kernel.

Or, you could lowpass filter the image and subtract the filtered image from the original image. And again if the difference is higher from an empirical threshold you may say that pixel is noisy.

I believe both of these methods may classify edges as noise so you may subtract the edges from the image and then use these methods.

Comment: could you provide an example?